# Deserializing JSON list property using GSON

Tags: java, gson

I'm attempting to deserialize some JSON that represents a process, where a process can have multiple sub-processes. The parent process is being created and populated properly. However the list of sub-processes has objects created as expected, but those objects are not populated.

Here is my json:

```
{       "name":"net.sample.parent",
        "id":19,
        "subProcesses":[{
                         "name":"net.sample.child",
                         "id":21,
                         "subProcesses":[],
                         "processVariables":{},
                         "openTasks":null,
                         "parentProcessId":null}],
        "processVariables":{
            "id":1,
            "startDate":"Aug 28, 2010 12:00:00 AM",
            "budget":10000.0,
            "userName":"mary",  
            "endDate":"Aug 28, 2011 12:00:00 AM"},
        "openTasks":null,
        "parentProcessId":null}
```

Here is my code that creates the GsonBuilder:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ProcessInstanceSummary.class, new ProcessInstanceCreator());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(HumanTask.class, new TaskInstanceCreator());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());

    public class TaskInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<HumanTask> {

        public HumanTask createInstance(Type type) {
            return new SimpleHumanTask();
        }
    }

    public class ProcessInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<ProcessInstanceSummary> {

        public ProcessInstanceSummary createInstance(Type type) {
            return new ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl();
        }
    }

    private class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonPrimitive asJsonPrimitive = json.getAsJsonPrimitive();

            return new Date(asJsonPrimitive.getAsLong());
        }
    }
```

The interface

```
public interface ProcessInstanceSummary {

    String getName();

    Long getId();

    Map<String, Object> getProcessVariables();

    List<HumanTask> getOpenTasks();

    List<ProcessInstanceSummary> getSubProcesses();

    Long getParentProcessId();
}
```

The Implementation :

```
public class ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl implements ProcessInstanceSummary {

    private String name;
    private Long id;
    private Map<String, Object> processVariables;
    private List<HumanTask> openTasks;
    private List<ProcessInstanceSummary> subProcesses;
    private Long parentProcess;

    /*
        No arg constructor here
        Getters and setters here.
    */

}
```

OK, so the result I get back when calling toObject looks like this:

```
dto ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl  (id=39) 
    id  Long  (id=71)   
    name    "net.sample.parent" (id=74) 
    openTasks   null    
    parentProcess   null    
    processVariables    LinkedHashMap<K,V>  (id=75) 
    subProcesses    ArrayList<E>  (id=57)   
        elementData Object[10]  (id=66) 
            [0] ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl  (id=69) 
                id  null    
                name    null    
                openTasks   null    
                parentProcess   null    
                processVariables    null    
                subProcesses    null    
            [1] null    
            [2] null    
            [3] null    
            [4] null    
            [5] null    
            [6] null    
            [7] null    
            [8] null    
            [9] null    
        modCount    1   
        size    1
```

As you can see an object of the correct type was created and added to the list of subProcesses but none of the properties have been populated.

If I just take the sub-process JSON and run it through the parser it works as expected.

Is there some step I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I fixed it. It turns out you need to make sure the list generic is set to the implementation. See below:

```
public class ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl implements ProcessInstanceSummary {

    private String name;
    private Long id;
    private Map<String, Object> processVariables;
    private List<HumanTask> openTasks;
    private List<ProcessInstanceSummaryImpl> subProcesses;
    private Long parentProcessId;

    /*
        No arg constructor here
        Getters and setters here.
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setters to your ProcessInstanceSummary interface, so that it can set the properties.

Comment: Adding setters to the interface didn't help. I believe GSON accesses the properties directly anyway. I fixed the properties on the implementation class to match the too. Changed parentProcess to parentProcessId and that made no difference.